# Is it possible to use vue-specific directives in localized text?

Tags: internationalization, vue.js, vuejs2

I just started using `vue-i18n` and tried to use the `v-on`-directive (shorthand: `@`) in my language specific text.

What i tried to do:

```
// locale definition
let locale = {
  en: {
    withEventListener: 'Some HTML with <a @click="onClickHandler">event handling</a>'
  }
}
```

and the vue template:

```
<!-- vue template be like -->
<p v-html="$t('withEventListener')" />
```

This doesn't throw an error but unfortunately it does not get evaluated by vue-js either. This would result to Plain-HTML like:

```
<p>
    Some HTML with <a @click="onClickHandler">event handling</a>
</p>
```

So my question is if there is a way to make Vue 'evaluate' the text and thus 'translate' the directives within the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vue.compile](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) to do something like this if you are including the standalone build script. I'm not familiar with `vue-i18n`, but this might put you on the right path.

Note that I had `withEventListener` to wrap it in a `div` because of the rules around templates.

```
let locale = {
  en: {
    withEventListener: '<div>Some HTML with <a @click="onClickHandler">event handling</a></div>'
  }
}

const res = Vue.compile(Vue.t("withEventListener"));

Vue.component("internationalized", {
  methods:{
    onClickHandler(){
      alert("clicked")
    }
  },
  render: res.render,
  staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
})


new Vue({
  el:"#app"
})
```

With the template

```
<div id="app">
  <internationalized></internationalized>
</div>
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PpzoXE?editors=1010).

Comment: GREAT! Thanks mate :)